# NumericUpDown error MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox, numericupdown

I would like to ask what code should I insert to to my "numGPA" to inform the user that they have exceeded the "maximum".

Right now if the try to "submit" a value above the maximum, my visual studio will only play a "ding" sound.

Instead of that I would like to have a message box that says something like "Only a value from 0 to 4 is allowed"

I found this code on Google and despite me changing the numericUpDown1 to numGPA it does not work.

```
        if (numGPA.Value >= 4 || numGPA.Value <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error. Number must be between 0 and 4");
            numGPA.Value = 1;
            numGPA.ReadOnly = true;
        }
```

Do take a look at this video to get a clear picture of what I am saying
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVv-it6x044&feature=youtu.be

Instead of the "ding" sound effect played @0.06, I would like a MessageBox.

Comment: If you use the Minimum and Maximum properties, the NumericUpDown can never have an invalid value and you wont need to annoy the user with a MessageBox.

Comment: Where is this code executed?  What event?

Comment: Message boxes are very rude and intrusive. A beep is much better. If you want to give a message, add a label next to the control, hide it, then show it with the message.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the TextChange event. You can (and should) also set the minimum and maximum properties to limit the input with the arrows.

```
Private Sub NumericUpDown1_Changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.TextChanged
If IsNumeric(NumericUpDown1.Text) AndAlso _
  CInt(NumericUpDown1.Text) > NumericUpDown1.Maximum Then MsgBox("Oops! Too big.")
End Sub
```

Comment: You must be aware that your answer isn't c#, right?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to let the user edit and only check when he has finished. This will trigger the `ValueChanged` event.

Here we can get at the entered value by grabbing the internal `TextBox` control.

I suggest using a helper function, maybe like this:

```
void nudCheck(NumericUpDown nud)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox) nud.Controls[1];
    if (Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text) > nud.Maximum)
    {
        string msg = tb.Text + " is too large! Setting value to maximum: " + nud.Maximum;
        tb.Text = "" + nud.Maximum;
        nud.Value = nud.Maximum;
        // do what you want with the message string!
        //MessageBox.Show(msg);   // not recommended!
        toolTip1.Show(msg, nud);  // add a ToolTip component to your form for this!
    }
}
```

Call it here:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    nudCheck(numericUpDown1);
}
```

We also want to suppress the error sound for the case when the user presses `Enter`, best in the `KeyDown` event..

```
private void numericUpDown1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
   {
       nudCheck(numericUpDown1);
       e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
   }
}
```

Note that bringing up an actual `MessageBox` will bring back the bell sound and force the user to get rid of it. So I have used a `ToolTip`, but a `Label` would also work, if you have the space..

Obviously you may want to add similar code to check input lower than the `Minimum`..